# How do I change rxvt colors to white on black?

Tags: virtual-console, rxvt

By default, on Ubuntu, rxvt terminal is black on white. How do I change it to white on black?

I'm running Lubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: You can launch it with `rxvt -fg white -bg black`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Note:**  Updated answer to include desktops like GNOME and LXDE that do not load `.Xresources` or `.Xdefault` files by default.  Also updated for packages `rxvt-unicode` and `rxvt` differences.

---

You can launch it with the command in a terminal window:

```
rxvt -fg white -bg black
```

which sets the foreground to white and the background to black.

Or you can launch it using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and typing it in:

[image]

Either way listed above should give you a `rxvt` terminal that looks like this:

[image]

**To make it permanent**, you can add the following lines to the end of your `~/.Xdefaults` or `~/.Xresources` file:

**Very important:**

If you installed `rxvt-unicode` add these lines to your `.Xresources` file:

```
URxvt*background: black
URxvt*foreground: white
```

If you installed just `rxvt` add these lines:

```
Rxvt*background: black
Rxvt*foreground: white
```

---

**URxvt can support more fonts.**

If you wanted to use a `Monospace 9` font with `urxvt`, add a line like this:

```
URxvt*font: xft:Monospace:size=9:antialias=true
```

Or you can use `fc-list | sort` to list all fonts available, then you can find one you want and set it like this:

```
URxvt*font: xft:DejaVu Sans Mono:size=9:antialias=true
URxvt*boldfont: xft:DejaVu Sans Mono:bold:size=9:antialias=true
```

**Rxvt has limited font support.**

If you run the command `xlsfonts` from a terminal window, it shows you all the fonts that can be loaded by `rxvt` instead of `urxvt`.  Here is some examples:

```
xlsfonts | less
```

The list will look something like this (truncating for space):

```
-arabic-newspaper-medium-r-normal--0-0-100-100-p-0-iso10646-1
-arabic-newspaper-medium-r-normal--32-246-100-100-p-137-iso10646-1
-bitstream-bitstream charter-bold-i-normal--0-0-0-0-p-0-adobe-standard
-bitstream-bitstream charter-bold-i-normal--0-0-0-0-p-0-ascii-0
-bitstream-bitstream charter-bold-i-normal--0-0-0-0-p-0-iso10646-1
-bitstream-bitstream charter-bold-i-normal--0-0-0-0-p-0-iso8859-1
-bitstream-bitstream charter-bold-r-normal--0-0-0-0-p-0-adobe-standard
-bitstream-bitstream charter-bold-r-normal--0-0-0-0-p-0-ascii-0
-bitstream-bitstream charter-bold-r-normal--0-0-0-0-p-0-iso10646-1
```

Or you can find a font you want using `xfontsel` and select all the settings you want and it will create the line you add like this:

[image]

You will just have to play around till you find one you like.

Add that line to your `.Xresources` file.

```
Rxvt*font: -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--13-120-75-75-c-70-iso8859-1
```

---

Anytime you `.Xdefaults` or `.Xresources` file(s), reload them with the following command(s) from a terminal window (requires restart of `rxvt` terminal if you are using it):

```
xrdb -load ~/.Xdefaults
```

or

```
xrdb -load ~/.Xresources
```

**Note:**  If you have a desktop like `LXDE` installed, these files do not load by default, but if you create `~/.xinitrc` with using which ever file you want as either `.Xresources` (recommended) or `.Xdefaults` and add the following line to the file:

```
xrdb -load ~/.Xresources &
```

Then make the `.xinitrc` executable:

```
chmod +x ~/.xinitrc
```

Reboot, then all you have to do is launch `rxvt` as normal.

---

*Screenshot from LXDE VM*

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: This doesn't do anything for me. Is there any way to troubleshoot it?

Comment: Ues, `rxvt -fg white -bg black` works as intended (and `~/.Xdefaults` or `~/.Xresources`) does not; and no, these files did not previously exist.

Comment: It's called `x11-xserver-utils` on Ubuntu and it's already installed. I have reinstalled, but no luck.

Comment: @NickolaiLeschov I have seen in another post that you are running LXDE, so I modified my answer to include how to make this work in LXDE, which I have tested myself in a VM and it works fine.

Comment: could you, by chance, tell how to change font in rxvt, too? E.g. "Monospace 9"

Comment: @Terrnace I think the font is not working.

Comment: It says "can't load font "$(font)",  whatever font I try. Also, seems like ther isn't a font named `Monospace`, though there are `Ubuntu Mono` and `FreeMono`?

Comment: ok, maybe I should make it a separate question.

Comment: @NickolaiLeschov Maybe you should.  I just looked at a Xfce installation and I still cannot get fonts to load with the rxvt.

Comment: @NickolaiLeschov Added one more part on using `xfontsel` to select the font you want that can be used by `rxvt`.  That is all I have.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, though all the font part is totally not working on my side.