# How to change the console of Code::Block in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: c++

I'm a newbie in Ubuntu.
And I want to change the fonts, size, color of console of CB. Please help me!

[image: I'm a newbie in Ubuntu. And I want to change the fonts, size, color of console of CB. Please help me!!]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that there is any one specific correct answer for this and it really is all about preference, but here is something I have come up with that might help.  This answer is [based on this answer that I wrote](https://askubuntu.com/a/882415/231142).

I recommend that you use any of the xterm terminal types. Probably the best one to use is `rxvt-unicode`

```
sudo apt install rxvt-unicode
```

Then in CodeBlocks go to *Settings -> Environment...*  then in the `Terminal to launch console programs` add the following:

```
urxvt -T $TITLE -e
```

[image]

Now, to change the colors and the fonts add like the following to your `~/.Xdefaults` file at the bottom:

```
URxvt*background: black
URxvt*foreground: white
```

Then one of the fonts that I kind of like is a monospace font and you can add it like the following below the above 2 lines:

```
URxvt*font: xft:Monospace:size=9:antialias=true
```

Save the `.Xdefaults` file and now you should get something looking like this:

[image]

Or you can change background colors to whatever you want.  Here's Cyan with Black text:

```
URxvt*background: cyan
URxvt*foreground: black
```

[image]

If you want to play around with different fonts that you can run from a terminal window:

```
fc-list | sort
```

And it should give you a list of available fonts.  Probably best to stick with any of the Mono type fonts.

Hope this helps!

Comment: My english is not good enough. Could you explain more from " Now, to change the colors and the fonts add like the following to your ~/.Xdefaults file at the bottom...", please....

Comment: @ManhHai Try looking at my linked older answer of https://askubuntu.com/questions/882405/how-do-i-change-rxvt-colors-to-white-on-black/882415#882415 where I try to go deeper in details of changing fronts and colors to the terminal.

Comment: how can i open ~/.Xdefault file ?

Comment: @ManhHai Use whatever editor you want like `gedit ~/.Xdefaults` or `nano ~/.Xdefaults`

Comment: by the way, could you help me to change the theme and the color on surrounding?

Comment: @ManhHai I think you are running GNOME and it is just the theme that you choose to change the looks.  See:  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuGNOME/HowTo#Theme  I am running Xfce4 as my Desktop Environment so its themes are different and changed differently.  You can always ask a new question on this site for changing themes or the look and feel of your desktop.